# Como crear usuarios con rango en CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tengo un problema al crear usuarios de diferente roles, ya que no cumple con la función que quiero.

Estoy tratando de que USUARIOS de diferentes ROLES/RANGOS/NIVELES tengan su espacio diferente por ej: 
Un **ADMIN** se redirija hacia > **dashboard_admin.php**

Un **USUARIO** se redirija hacia > **dashboard.php**

Un **MODERADOR** se redirija hacia > **dasboard_mod.php**

Támbien trato que al obtener tal rango un mensaje en el dasboard aparezca como "Tu Rango es: **ADMIN/USUARIO/MODERADOR**"

Dejo aqui mi archivo **User.php**

````php
class Cl_User
{
    /**
     * @var va a contener la conexión de base de datos
     */
    protected $_con;

    /**
     * Inializar DBclass
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $db = new Cl_DBclass();
        $this->_con = $db->con;
    }

/**
     * Este metodo para iniciar sesión
     * @param array $data
     * @return retorna falso o verdadero
     */ 

public function login( array $data )
    {
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = false;
        if( !empty( $data ) ){

            // Trim todos los datos entrantes:
            $trimmed_data = array_map('trim', $data);

            // escapar de las variables para la seguridad
            $email = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con,  $trimmed_data['email'] );
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con,  $trimmed_data['password'] );
            $key_asc = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con,  $trimmed_data['key_asc'] );
                        $creditos = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con,  $trimmed_data['creditos'] );
                        $level = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con,  $trimmed_data['level'] );

            if((!$email) ||  (!$password) ||  (!$key_asc) ) {
                throw new Exception( LOGIN_FIELDS_MISSING );
            }
            $password = md5( $password );
            $query = "SELECT user_id, name, email, key_asc, creditos, level FROM users where ( email = '$email' and key_asc = '$key_asc' ) and password = '$password'";
            $result = mysqli_query($this->_con, $query);
            $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            mysqli_close($this->_con);
            if( $count == 1){
                $_SESSION = $data;
                $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
                return true;
            }else{
                throw new Exception( LOGIN_FAIL );
            }
        } else{
            throw new Exception( LOGIN_FIELDS_MISSING );
        }
    }```

Desde ya agradezco cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar.
````

Comment: Hola @Joaqho C no se si ya resolviste el problema, pero hay varias formas de validar lo que haces, puedes armar una arquitectura de base de datos que contenga todo lo que requieres y hacer todo muy dinamico, o simplemente crear un switch o if y validar si "variable rol" es igual administrador redirect('dashboard_admin') y lo mismo con los demas roles, hay que tener en cuenta que no lo estas redigiriendo directamente al archivo sino al metodo que abre ese archivo..... un saludo.

Comment: Gracias @JDavid ya pude resolverlo, con un If.